# How to change default audio devices in pjsip

Tags: raspberry-pi3, pjsip

I would like to change default playback and capture audio device in pjsip library  to  usb audio codec and IQAudio DAC which is connected externally to Raspberry pi compute module 3+ .I tried by running pjsua binary with following arguments.

```
    sudo ./pjsua-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --config-file <config file name> --playback-dev=0 --capture-dev=1
```

following are the record and playback devices.

aplay -l

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****

card 0: IQaudIODAC [IQaudIODAC], device 0: IQaudIO DAC HiFi pcm512x-hifi-0 [IQaudIO DAC HiFi pcm512x-hifi-0]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 1: Device [USB PnP Sound Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

arecord -l

**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****

card 1: Device [USB PnP Sound Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

But I am not able to select the desired Audio devices.
By default it is taking usb audio codec as playback and capture device.How can we change the audio devices from default to desired ones.Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance